# How to deploy an ASP.NET MVC app to Server 2012 R2?

Tags: iis, deployment

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS (v. 6.2). I have an ASP.NET MVC application with .NET 4.7.2.

Is it possible to deploy the web app to the server? I have read that this operation had been done using a utility called Web Deployment. But Web Deployment now is obsolete and does not exist on MS website anymore.

Comment: It would surely make more sense to invest your time into upgrading the server, Windows 2012R2 is 11 years old and (from now) about 3 months before reaching end-of support.

Comment: It's rather interesting that you claimed Web Deploy is obsolete, but it isn't https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

Answer (score 1):

Earlier versions of Web Deploy have reached end of life, but currently Web Deploy 3.6 is still a supported version and can be downloaded from this link: [Web Deploy 3.6](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy).

Web Deploy 3.6 works with: IIS 7, IIS 7.5, IIS 8, IIS 8.5, IIS 10. You are using Windows Server 2012 R2, which includes IIS version 8.5, so you can use Web Deploy to deploy web applications and websites to the IIS server.